# Oracle Shutdown Method

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Shutting down a database before doing an upgrade or a patch can be done several ways.

```
shutdown immediate;
```

or

```
shutdown abort;
startup restrict;
shutdown immediate;
```

or

```
shutdown abort;
startup restrict;
shutdown;
```

or

```
alter system checkpoint;
shutdown abort;
startup restrict;
shutdown immediate;
```

Of course there are other options as well.  Which should be preferred and why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The aim when shutting down for maintenance (or cold backup) is that the database is left in a consistent state with no need for rollback/recovery on startup.

There are 3 SQL*Plus `shutdown` commands that achieve this in theory, all of which immediately prevent *new* sessions connecting to the instance:

1. [`shutdown normal`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/start003.htm#ADMIN11157) or just `shutdown`: waits for all sessions to disconnect. This mode is rarely used in practice because it relies on well-behaved clients not leaving connections open. This used to be the only `shutdown` mode that did not cancel running transactions.
2. [`shutdown transactional`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/start003.htm#ADMIN11159): disconnects sessions once currently running transactions complete, preventing new transactions from beginning.
3. [`shutdown immediate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/start003.htm#ADMIN11158): disconnects all sessions immedately and rolls back interrupted transactions before shutting down. Note that the disconnections are immediate, but *the shutdown may not be* as any interrupted transactions may take time to roll back.

The fourth mode of `shutdown` is [`shutdown abort`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/start003.htm#ADMIN11160). This is like pulling the power cord - the instance stops *now* without any cleanup. You usually want to bring the database up again afterwards and shut down cleanly immediately afterwards as in your example. The concepts guide [says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/startup.htm#CNCPT89041):

> This mode is intended for emergency situations, such as when no other form of shutdown is successful.

All the examples you give [perform a checkpoint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/startup.htm#CNCPT89041) as part of the `shutdown [normal]` or `shutdown immediate` so explicit checkpointing is presumably to [reduce the time required for recovery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/startup.htm#CNCPT89043).

general advice:

- Do not use `shutdown normal`.
- Use `shutdown transactional` *for attended shutdown only*, when you want to minimise cancelled transactions (attended only because this kind of shutdown [is not guaranteed to shut the database down](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/start003.htm#ADMIN11161) at all if timeouts are breached).
- Use `shutdown immediate` for unattended shutdown or when you do not care about currently running transactions.
- Do not use `shutdown abort` (plus startup/shutdown) unless you have to - this was more common in much earlier versions of Oracle that it is today. In other situations (not patch/upgrade), if you have a need to [minimise downtime](http://www.speakeasy.org/~jwilton/oracle/shutdown-abort-bad.html) this mode may be appropriate.

Comment: Can you provide any more specifics on the disadvantages of `shutdown abort`?  Playing the antagonist, if we can trust Oracle to recover correctly when the power is pulled, shouldn't we trust it during a `shutdown abort`, particularly if it is faster and we are going to immediately do a `startup restrict` and a `shutdown immediate`?  In other words, are there facts we can see to back up Oracle's dire warning against `shutdown abort`?

Comment: @Leigh - The only specific danger I know of concerning `shutdown abort` relates to [accidental backup of online logs](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1892210373157) but that is only in the case you do not subsequently do a clean shutdown. If you know what you are doing I think `shutdown abort` can be considered perfectly safe - and I'm not sure if Oracle's position counts as a "dire warning" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the *shutdown abort* method because it is the fastest way to bring a database down. there are some operation that cannot be done after a shutdown abort, e.g

- recreate the controlfile the database with *create controlfile resetlogs* (to rename the database, to rename teh logfiles of to rename datafiles)
- change the dbid with the procedure from dbms_backup_restore (this was the only method in 8i to change the dbid)

in both cases the database was damaged and must be restored from a fullbackup.

since 9i the rename of the database or the change of the dbid can be done with the *dbnewid* utility. as far as I know the utility checks if the database was shutdown correctly. renaming datafiles, tempfiles and logfiles can be done by executing the appropriate sql statements without recreating the controlfile of course.