# Oracle: force shutdown as root without knowing logins

Tags: oracle, shutdown

I am root on a GNU/Linux machine with Oracle 10.2.0.1.0 XE installed. I need to shut down Oracle, but I do not have admin logins to Oracle.

How do I as root force Oracle to shutdown?

I have a normal user login. When using that I get:

```
ORA-01089: immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted
```

This does not change even if I run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe restart
```

I have the feeling I need to create an administrative user from the Unix prompt, login in as this user, and run some magic command (probably one of [Oracle Shutdown Method](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15888/oracle-shutdown-method)).

My guess is you probably need to fiddle with these files:

```
$ ls $ORACLE_HOME/dbs
hc_XE.dat  init.ora  lkXE  orapwXE  spfileXE.ora
```

But exactly what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shutdown is already in progress. You can either

1. Wait
2. Login using `su - oracle` and then `sqlplus / as sysdba` and issue the command `shutdown abort` if that's what you really want.